# How can I only load a Shopify Section element on desktop?

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have a few video tags on my landing page that show up on Desktop, but I want to hide them on mobile. I'm currently doing this with CSS which visually works, but `display:none` doesn't stop the video from actually loading which ruins the point (improving page speed, decreasing data usage, etc). I tried using the following `javascript` within the `{% javascript %}` schema section of my custom Shopify section, but it's not working properly and not showing up when I view the source code of the website in Chrome.

```
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
   $( ".case-study-bg-video" ).append( $( "<source src='{{ section.settings.video_url }}' type='video/mp4'>" ) );
}
```

The `.case-study-bg-video` is an html video tag, and the goal is to only load the source tag if the screen size is above `767px`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you open the console (Keyboard shortcut: F12 for most browsers running on Windows), do you see any errors?

Comment: When Shopify renders your Liquid into a giant string of HTML, JS and CSS, it has no a priori idea of what it is rendering to. A 40" monitor or a dinky phone screen. Therefore, once the Liquid render is done, and your browser is loaded with code, you can examine the window size. Once there, you can decide if you're on a big or small screen. Then and only then would you download your video. 

So that is hacky, but essentially, is that not the way you see it working?

Comment: @DaveB I don't see any errors relating to that script, no. When I view page source code, the script doesn't show up so it doesn't seem to be rendering at all

Comment: @DavidLazar that's exactly how I planned for it to work, correct. I agree it feels a bit hacky, but couldn't think of another solution - do you have any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you change the Liquid `{% javascript %}` & `{% endjavascript %}` to a regular `<script>` & `</script>` tag?

Comment: @DaveB if I use a script tag it shows in the page source, but still isn't executing properly for some reason. I pasted the same script in Console of Inspect Element and it did work though, so I'm not too sure what the problem is...

Comment: Hmm. Is your script above the element that you're trying to affect? If it is, it could be that your code is running before the element exists.  If so, you could fix it by moving your script closer to the bottom of the snippet or by wrapping your code with `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){  /** your code here **/   })` to make sure it doesn't execute until all of the HTML is on the page.

Comment: @DaveB sorry for the late response, but that helped! The script is now running, but have run into another issue... If I have multiple of these section on a page, the <source> tag is inject into all of them. This makes sense, but obviously is not ideal. The best workaround would probably be generating unique class names for the section - do you know how I could do this?

Comment: Each section _should_ have a unique `{{ section.id }}` that you could append to the class to make unique classnames

Comment: @DaveB just what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was placement of the script within the section file. Rather than wrapping it in the {% Javascript %} schema section I just placed it in a  tag above the schema and wrapped it in the following:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){  /** your code here **/   })
```

Then to solve issues with multiple sections on the same page, I appended {{ section.id }} to add the video in the right spot.